# Would skipping part of a loop in a kernel result in warp divergence?

Tags: cuda

I have a loop in my CUDA kernel like this:

```
for-each(e in source-array)
{
    if(xxx(e)) continue;

    Do something ...
}
```

**source-array** is a array which is broadcasted to all kernels, but different thread executes **continue** at different time. But through out the array, **continue** triggers for fixed times.

Well, I know there will certainly be warp divergence when some threads executes **continue** while others **Do Something**, but will these threads starts together again at next loop(i.e for the next **e**)? Or the thread would wait until other threads finished the whole for-each loop?

Comment: @user703016 So, whenever the **if** statment excecutes, all the threads are always working on the same **e** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of warp divergence, the threads that hit the `xxx(e)` condition will wait for the other threads in the warp to reach the end of the loop, after which the execution paths will converge back.